# Prevent div-overlapping only on window resize (w/ Styled Components)

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, styled-components

I have a header-component that has a title to the left and some links to the right of the page. The size and position of these divs are (partially) responsive and I am happy with the way they move along when I resize my window. However, I would like the left div to act as a wall for the others. As in when I resize my window to really small the links will 'hit' the title and only then start wrapping into multiple lines. How can I do this?

```html
<html>
   <head>
     <style>
       .body {  
          position: fixed;
          top: 0;
          background-color: lightgoldenrodyellow;
          box-sizing: border-box;
          width: 100vw;
          height: calc(2% + 75px);
          z-index: 10000;
        }

        .titleContainer {
          position: fixed;
          left: 0;
          display: flex;
          align-items: center;
          font-size: calc(18px + 0.5vw);
          width: 250px;
          min-width: 200px; 
          height: calc(2% + 75px);
          transition: 0.3s;
          margin-left: 10px;
        }
        .titleContainer:hover{
          cursor: pointer;
        }

        #title {
          margin-right: auto;
          padding-left: 5px;
          text-decoration: none;
          font-size: 32px;
          font-weight: 750;
          font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
        }

        .pageLinkContainer {
          position: fixed;
          right: 0;
          display: flex;
          flex-direction: row;
          justify-content: center;
          align-items: center;
          height: calc(2% + 75px);
          width: auto;
        }

        .pageLink {
          margin-right: 10px;
          margin-left: 2px;
          font-size: calc(12px + 0.3vw);
        }
      </style>
   </head>
   <body>
      <div className="titleContainer">
        <h3><Link id="title" to="/" >TITLE</Link></h3>
      </div>

      <div className="pageLinkContainer">
        <Link className="pageLink" to="/upload">Upload a funny Gif</Link> &nbsp;
        <Link className="pageLink" to="/gifs"> Look at funny Gifs</Link> &nbsp;
        <Link className="pageLink" to="/database">Database</Link> &nbsp;
      </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

EDIT #3:

As per **Niwo**'s answer below, here's my current css. I use Styled Components that create a body as a wrapper around the component. I've tried to explain the flow of the page as clearly as possible. Another idea I had was to use the `window.innerWidth` to make the links disappear if the window is resized.

I've updated this CSS to the working answer, for anyone who cares to know. I've also added back in my styled Components (which I removed in order to remove the React from this). All credits go to **Niwo** of course.

**CSS**

```
//GLOBAL STYLE 

const GlobalStyle = createGlobalStyle`

body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    background-color: rgba(0,0,50,0.3);
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    position: absolute;
}
`


//GLOBAL CONTAINER
//A WRAPPER-DIV AROUND ALL COMPONENTS

const GlobalContainer = styled.div`
{
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}
`


//HEADER COMPONENT
//ANOTHER WRAPPER-DIV JUST FOR THIS COMPONENT

const HeaderStyle = styled.div`
{
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  background-color: rgba(100,200,100,0.6);
  width: 100vw;
  height: calc(2% + 75px);
  z-index: 10000;
}


.titleContainer {
    display: flex;
    flex-shrink: 0;
    align-items: center;
    font-size: calc(18px + 0.5vw);
    width: 250px;
    transition: 0.3s;
    margin-left: 10px;
  }
.titleContainer:hover{
    cursor: pointer;
  }

#title {
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 32px;
    font-weight: 750;
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  }

.pageLinkContainer {
    right: 0;
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    height: calc(2% + 75px);
  }

.pageLink {
    white-space: nowrap;
    margin: 0 0.5rem;
    font-size: calc(12px + 0.3vw);
  }
`
```

**HTML**

```
<GlobalStyle />
   <GlobalContainer>
        <HeaderStyle>
            <div className="titleContainer">
                <h3><Link id="title" to="/" >Movie Scores</Link></h3>
            </div>

            <div className="pageLinkContainer">
                <Link className="pageLink" to="/upload">Upload a funny Gif</Link>&nbsp;
                <Link className="pageLink" to="/gifs"> Look at funny Gifs</Link>&nbsp;
                <Link className="pageLink" to="/database">Movies We've Seen</Link>&nbsp;
            </div>
        </HeaderStyle>
   </GlobalContainer>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Use flexbox to prevent other elements from overlapping

If you want the solution on fiddle, it's right here: https://jsfiddle.net/Niwo04/o1df63L2/1/

I've cleaned your code a bit up and replaced your React stuff with normal HTML (because I don't know something about React). I also did some coloring, because I thought that might make everything visually better to understand.

If you have any questions about my changes, feel free to reply on this answer ; )

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  background-color: darkgray;
}

.body {
  position: fixed;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  background-color: lightgoldenrodyellow;
  width: 100vw;
  height: 75px;
  z-index: 10000;
}

.titleContainer {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  width: 250px;
  background-color: red;
  flex-shrink: 0;
}

.pageLinkContainer {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  background-color: blue;
}

.pageLink {
  white-space: nowrap;
  margin: 0 0.5rem;
}
```

```html
<html>

<body>
  <div class="body">
    <div class="titleContainer">
      <h3>TITLE</h3>
    </div>

    <div class="pageLinkContainer">
      <a class="pageLink">Upload a funny Gif</a>
      <a class="pageLink">Look at funny Gifs</a>
      <a class="pageLink">Database</a>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Hi! It's not really working for me, though your example on jsfiddle is kind of what I want! I have edited my post above with the update code. The pagelinks still slide under the title on the left when I resize my window. Also I had to fix them to the right with ```right: 0``` otherwise they wouldn't stay in the Header somehow.

Comment: Hello daritimm, first you need to know that flexbox isn't working if you position the elements fixed. But I think we don't have the same HTML, because in your original post is this class called "body", but there is no element wich has this class attached to and when I was writing my answer I added a div with this class as surrounding element for your title and your links. This div is basically the main flexbox element wich controls the position of the title and the links. Can you please update the HTML in your post too, so I can work with the current version of your HTML and CSS.

Comment: Hi Niwo, I see about the fixed elements. But if I don't fix the header, it's not stuck to the top. How can we make this happen? As to the body: I have an element called ```<HeaderStyle>``` which is a styled components thing for React. Basically it's a wrapper for this specific 'component', ie. the Header which works as a body afaik. If I add a separate body-div a bunch of things stop working however so that may be something I need to look into.

Comment: Basically what happens if I take away ```position: fixed``` is that the Header gets dropped lower because the entire page is in flex mode (through a global style-sheet). I'll try to add that in my post, though it gets a bit muddy I must admit.

Comment: Is this like your current HTML and CSS (https://jsfiddle.net/Niwo04/p9vgyLox/24/)? If so, I can agree that you need `position: fixed` to attach the element with the class "another-styled-div" to the top, but then you don't need `position: fixed` for your title and the links, because the "another-styled-div" is holding them at the top of the page. I really need your current HTML, not only the CSS, because in your original post is no "another-styled-div" or a "main-styled-div".

Comment: Hi Niwo, thanks so much for sticking with me here. You fixed it! Your example is exactly as my screen, yes. Removing the ```position: fixed``` from the title and links works perfectly. Very happy to have learned that flexbox and position fixed can't be used at the same time. If I could upvote twice, I would.

Comment: Thank you. I'm glad that it helped you and that you know a bit more about fixed navbars with flexbox. It's better to know why an answer is working rather than just using it without knowing what's exactly going on in the code. I wish you much success with your project and always feel free to ask again if you are in trouble with your code ; )